# test with liftweb S.rederectTo

Tags: testing, lift

I'm currently doing a web project on liftweb. And I would like to write a test case for a snippet which is having a `S.redirectTo` clause.

This redirection creates an error on my test case. is there any way of testing a method with `S.redirectTo`?

Answer (score 0):

S.redirectTo throws a ResponseShortcutException in order to redirect the flow of control.

In your test case, put a try/catch around the call to your snippet to explicitly handle this exception, something like:

```
try {
  ...
  mySnippet(...)
  ...
} catch {
  case ex: ResponseShortcutException => // Assert if this is what you expect
}
```